# log error- apache

Tags: logging

How can i solve this issue in vertigo?

```
[Thu May 19 23:19:19 2011] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/Users/fel/VertrigoServ/www/login/.htaccess: 

 Invalid command 'ExpiresActive', perhaps mis-spelled or defined by
 a module not included in the server configuration
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it

```
Settings> Extensions Settings > mod_expires SO
```

Close and Restart server